# Can I delete any unwanted file or folder in already written CD or DVD?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, dvd-burning, disk-utility

I have a DVD which is already written few folders along with files, but now I want to delete few unwanted folders along with files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If the CD or DVD was **not closed** (i.e. not finalized) after it was recorded, you can continue your session anytime, i.e. you can add/remove the files and folders you want. This is what I usually do with non-rewritable discs.

The option to close a disc can be found on "Write Options" dialog box in most of the CD/DVD burning programs. Just uncheck it to make sure you can add/remove files to your disc later.

[image]

Comment: so how to delete files if the disk is not finalized ?

Comment: Open your disc-writing tool and delete the relevant files from your disc using the app interface. @pheromix

Answer (score 0):

Unless the disk support rewritting ( i.e. DVDRW ) this is not possible. If you are dealing with non-rewrittable disk ( i.e. CDRW, DVDRW, BR+RW ) they are design to be written to once. You also have to have the ability to write to these rewrittable disks